# unrecognized selector error on methods of a subproject

Tags: objective-c, ios5, subproject

I have added a 3rd party library as a subproject following the steps under "Usage" section of the following link

http://cocoanetics.github.com/DTCoreText/

However, after adding the subproject, my project builds properly, but i am not able to call any methods which are defined in the subproject, and i am getting following errors :

```
[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithHTMLData:documentAttributes:]: unrecognized selector
    sent to instance 0x71141e0
2012-10-01 17:34:30.600 final_try[7785:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   
  exception NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString 
  initWithHTMLData:documentAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71141e0
  *** First throw call stack:
 (0x1971012 0x1796e7e 0x19fc4bd 0x1960bbc 0x196094e 0x22a4 0x1f1e 0x6db7b7 0x6dbda7 
  0x6dcfab    0x6ee315 0x6ef24b 0x6e0cf8 0x1deedf9 0x1deead0 0x18e6bf5 0x18e6962 0x1917bb6 
  0x1916f44 0x1916e1b 0x6dc7da 0x6de65c 0x1c9d 0x1bc5 0x1)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The implementation file has the following code :

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mailBody1" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

str1 = [str1 gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
NSData *data = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
_html = str1;

NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:data documentAttributes:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",[string plainTextString]);

NSLog(@"%@",string);

return self;
```

Comment: Fixed it !! I just needed to add "libDTCoreText.a" static library under the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under my application target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it !! I just needed to add "libDTCoreText.a" static library under the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under my application target

Comment: I am having the same issue, but adding the lib does not fix the problem.

Comment: make sure you've got "-ObjC" under Other Linker Flags in Build Settings :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try change `initWithHTMLData` to `initWithHTML`? So something like this:

```
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data documentAttributes:NULL];
```

I don't think there's a method as you call it.

The method I'm referring to can be found [at this link](http://cocoanetics.github.com/DTCoreText/Classes/DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder.html#//api/name/initWithHTML%3aoptions%3adocumentAttributes%3a).

Comment: you are referring to the right docs, but the DTCoreText library has few more files and this method "initWithHTMLData exists in file called "NSAttributString+HTML". Also, this line i've just copied from the DTCoreText itself. So should work.

Comment: are you including that file in your file?

Comment: You gonna need the "Other Linker Flags" -all_load and -ObjC, too!

Answer (score 0):

Another fix that might be required, other than Jerry's answer of ensuring libDTCoreText.a is linked is adding "-ObjC" to Other Linker Flags under the project's Build Settings.